# JS Multidimensional arrays and iteration

Tags: javascript

```
          var cubes = [
                      ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                      ['f','g','h','i','j'],
                      ['k','l','m','n','o']

                      ]

          var tmp = []

          for(var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++)
          {
              var cube = cubes[i];

              var step = 0

              for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++)
              {
                  tmp.push((cube[j])) // DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE
              }
          }
```

I want the first letter of every array to join, then take the second letter of every array, then the third letter, combining them to make an encryted word.
Each encrypted word.length should be max 5 characteers. If you read down from the array, it will create the encryption.

Example output for the above: afkbg lchmd inejo

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: It's one small part of  a homework assignment, I still had to make the sub arrays out of user input messages, etc. This is prob the last stretch

Comment: cubes[i][j] would access the element in each list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an array for words which we are eventually going to return
2. Find the length of the "x-axis"
3. Loop through the "x-axis" and the "y-axis", concatenating the last entry in the words array with the current symbol
4. If the last entry in the words array has a length greater than max, push a new empty string to work on
5. Return the array

```js
/**
 * cubesToWord
 *
 * @param {string[][]} cubes
 * @param {number} [maxLength=5]
 * @returns {string[]}
 */
function cubesToWord(cubes, maxLength) {
  if (maxLength === void 0) {
    maxLength = 5;
  }
  var words = [''];
  var maxX = cubes.map(function(value) {
    return value.length;
  }).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return (curr > prev ? curr : prev);
  }, 0);
  for (var x = 0; x < maxX; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < cubes.length; y++) {
      if (cubes[y] != void 0 ? cubes[y][x] == void 0 : true) {
        continue;
      }
      words[words.length - 1] += cubes[y][x];
      if (words[words.length - 1].length >= maxLength) {
        words.push("");
      }
    }
  }
  return words.filter(function(val) {
    return val.length > 0;
  });
}
//TEST
var cubes = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
  ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
];
console.log(cubesToWord(cubes, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flatten** the *2-dimensional array* **column-wise first** using `reduce`, `map` and `join`

```
var flattenStr = cubes[0].reduce( (a, c, i1) => a.concat( cubes.map( ( s, i2 ) => s[i1] ) ) , [] ).join("");
```

Now split this string into 5 chunks using `match`

```
var output = flattenStr.match(/.{1,5}/g)
```

**Demo**

```js
var cubes = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
  ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
];

var flattenStr = cubes[0].reduce((a, c, i1) => a.concat(cubes.map((s, i2) => s[i1])), []).join("");


var output = flattenStr.match(/.{1,5}/g);

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

var rectangle = cubes[0].reduce((a, c, i1) => a.concat(cubes.map((s, i2) => s[i1])), []).join("");

```
var encryption = rectangle.match(/.{1,5}/g);

console.log("Your encryption is as follows: \n" + encryption.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate an array with joined columns and generate an array with strings with the wanted length.

```js
var cubes = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']],
    size = 5,
    result = cubes
        .reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => (r[i] || '') + v), [])
        .join('')
        .match(new RegExp('.{1,' + size + '}', 'g'));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take easiest method for student.

```
var cubes = [
    ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    ['f','g','h','i','j'],
    ['k','l','m','n','o']
]
var tmp = [];
var word = [];
for(var j=0;j<5;j++) {
    for(var i=0;i<cubes.length;i++) {
        word.push(cubes[i][j])
        if(word.length == 5) {
            tmp.push(word.join(''));
            word = []
        }
    }
}
var crypted = tmp.join(' ')
console.log(crypted);
```

This read array from top to down just as human does.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cubes = [
    ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    ['f','g','h','i','j'],
    ['k','l','m','n','o']
]
let tmp = [];
let word = [];

for(let j=0;j<cubes[0].length;j++) {
    for(let i=0;i<cubes.length;i++) {
        word.push(cubes[i][j])
        if(word.length == 5) {
            tmp.push(word.join(''));
            word = []
        }
    }
}
console.log(tmp.join(' '))
```